# Power BI DAX not calculating Year over Year (YoY%) change

Tags: powerbi, dax, formula

I have the following DAX code:

```
VAR __PREV_YEAR =
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('data'[Inbounds]),
        DATEADD('MonthLookup'[YearMonth].[Date], -1, YEAR)
    )
RETURN
    DIVIDE(SUM('data'[Inbounds]) - __PREV_YEAR, __PREV_YEAR)
```

Month Lookup Table looks like this:

[MonthLookup Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7atHn.png)

Data has a YearMonth Column as well:

[YearMonth Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3KmH.png)

However, the DAX code shows as 0% with DateAdd based on MonthLookup, whereas setting DateAdd on data tables YearMonth results in an error.
[DAX YoY% change error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQS5T.png)

Comment: DateAdd is a time intelligence function, and it requires dates to work properly. YearMonth looks like a text, not a date. To solve the problem, build a proper calendar date, where each record is a day.

Comment: @RADO I have some tables aggregated at the month level, and some tables by date. How would I go about stitching those together without breaking my filtering settings?

Comment: For tables that are on a month level, instead of year-month key use first date of the month. I.e, instead of 2020-Jan, use 2020-01-01. Then calendar table will work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerBI date logic works best if you create a Calendar/Dates table (PowerBI has an auto feature to create one quickly) which has a date for each day in your data's date range. (Lots of examples if you google on doing this).  You then can join your Dates from the Data table.  Once done, you can leverage all the period functions in powerBI to prior period values. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/time-intelligence-functions-dax.

Your calculation would be something like this:

```
YOY=
VAR PriorYear = Calculate(SUM('data'[Inbounds]),PREVIOUSYEAR('Dates'[Date]))
RETURN TOTALYTD(SUM('data'[Inbounds]),'Dates'[Date])-PriorYear
```

A typical date table might look something like this:

[image]

Comment: one minor detail, I have many tables that have data aggregated at the monthly level, but not at the date level. How would I tie all of it together without breaking the filtering settings?

Comment: I've added a picture of a sample date table.  By using this table you can rollup your data by Year or Month, or Create a hierarchy so you can drill down.

Comment: @GunterHerd https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/model-date-tables might be helpful as well. might also be helpful.